# Flask helper method to find user from header

Tags: flask, python-requests

I am playing around with Flask. I like that it is fairly thin and works for most of my requirements.

I would like to know what is your recommended way of retrieving the current logged in user. I would like every HTTP request, which is made, to pass/carry a **token** in the header, which is first retrieved by the **login api**

```
/user/login (params: username, password)
# returns {success: True, token: "<some-unique-string>"
```

Now is the subsequent APIs I would like to get the user object from the from passed token, like so

```
@app.route("/user/info", methods = ["GET"])
@apify
def user_get_info():
   return {"name": current_user().name}
```

How could I have current_user read from the header without having to pass the **request** object every time ?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Every token is stored against a user. So you can make a query to get a user against a given token. Something like:

```
token = Token.query.get(token='token_value')
return jsonify({'name: User.query.get(id=token.user_id).name})
```

This can be done in one line as well but it totally depends upon your models and relationships.

Hope that helps. If I haven't understood your question correctly, do elaborate a little.